# como guardar el resultado de una consulta en una variable

Tags: sql

estoy debugeando este codigo

```
SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT LOCT_LOGIN_EMAIL from LOCT_LOGIN_V Where LOCT_LOGIN_USUARIO=@usuario", cnsec);
           cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usuario", usuario);
```

quisiera guardar una variable con el resultado

uso esto

```
correo = cmd2.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
```

pero no funciona

help "/

Comment: porque no funciona? que error recibis?

Comment: Hola, ¿podrías especificar el lenguaje y el gestor de base de datos que estas utilizando? a simple vista diría que estas utilizando C# y SQL Server pero no estoy muy seguro.

Comment: asi es c# y sql server 2008 r2

Comment: ya quedo amigos agradesco su ayuda